# Finding an algorithm using Householder transformations for reducing a matrix to upper triangular form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}R\\ S\end{bmatrix}$ where $R_{n\times n}$ is upper triangular and $S_{m\times n}$ is dense. Describe an algorithm using Householder transformations for reducing $A$ to upper triangular form.

for $i=1$ to $\min(m-1,n)$

$u_i=House(A(i+n:m+n,i))$

$P_i'=I-2u_iu_i^T$

$A(i+n:m+n,i:n)=P_i'A(i+n:m+n,i:n)$

end for

I'm assuming this is simpler than I'm expecting it to be and could be much shorter than the algorithm I provided

Comment: You should care that the format of matrix $A$ is $(m+n)\times n$. Your loop bounds make no sense currently. // Note that the $R$ block remains upper triangular in every step.

Comment: Can you check the algorithm again? I updated the row bounds for the matrix

Comment: No. The idea should be that you rotate or reflect the content of the $S$ columns directly into the diagonal element of $R$ above. As such you construct the reflector with $A(i:m+n,i)$. One can note that $A(i+1:n,i)$ is zero, so that the corresponding rows are not influenced by the reflector.